# Webscraping with Python/scrapy (does this code work)

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

Im a python novice and a newbie that tries to learn some python and mainly to scrape with it. I have managed to do some simple scrapers but now im working on a more advanced script.

With a csv file i have i try to read that col by col and for each value in a column im going to post this value in a webform.

I found here on stackoverflow a script that does exactly this but i cant get it to scrape anything for me and because i dont understand all this im having trouble to get my mainspider to work properly too.

The spider crawls but the only thing it returns with feed exports is one "["

Here is the older thread [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682463/scrape-using-multiple-post-data-from-the-same-url)

Here is the code for the spider.

```
import csv
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class BtwItem(Item):
    fttcAvailable = Field()
    phoneNumber = Field()


class BtwSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "btw"
    allowed_domains = ["samknows.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request("http://www.samknows.com/broadband/broadband_checker", self.parse_main_page)

    def parse_main_page(self, response):
        with open('phones.csv', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                phone_number = row[0]
                yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                                formdata={'broadband_checker[phone]': phone_number},
                                                callback=self.after_post,
                                                meta={'phone_number': phone_number})

    def after_post(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@id="results"]')

        phone_number = response.meta['phone_number']
        for site in sites:
            item = BtwItem()

            fttc = site.select("div[@class='content']/div[@id='btfttc']/ul/li/text()").extract()
            item['phoneNumber'] = phone_number
            item['fttcAvailable'] = 'not' in fttc[0]

            yield item
```

And here is som example numbers in the phones.csv file

```
01253873647
01253776535
01142726749
```

Comment: A few remarks/questions: where is the "[" retrieved? Your `start_requests` seems useless to me since you don't do anything there. Why don't you replace your `parse_main_page` with a `start_requests` function? After all this is where you really start the work, you don't need to connect to the website first then callback this function. Are you sure the page you crawl in the `after_post` function is the correct one? You should insert a pdb (http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) at the beginning of `after_post` and see what you really are parsing. And your final xpath could be shortened!

Answer (score 0):

See here for info on obtaining API access:
http://www.samknows.com/dataoutput

In any case, this may get you started:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.samknows.com/broadband/broadband_checker'
num = '01253873647'

data = {'broadband_checker[phone]': num, 
        'broadband_checker[postcode]': '',}

s = BeautifulSoup((requests.post(url, data=data)).text)
s.find('div', attrs={'id':'summary'}).prettify()
```

Comment: I could have used the API, but since im trying to learn this method of scraping, and my project is not really about samknows.com i would really like to know why i cant get my above content to scrape any data. But thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your spider code is not working is because your indentation is incorrect. I edited your question to correctly indent the code, assuming that the indentation error was a copy paste issue. Please copy the updated code above exactly as posted and the spider will work.